# Dispatching events from a ActionScript class

Tags: apache-flex

```
package com.services
{

        import com.asfusion.mate.events.ResponseEvent;
        import com.events.navigation.DesgManagementEvent
        import flash.events.EventDispatcher;    
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        public class UserManager extends EventDispatcher
        {

          [Bindable]
            public var addResult:String

               [Bindable]
            public var user:User

            public function UserManager()
            {
            }


            public function addUsersResult(Result:String):void {        
                addResult = Result
                //Alert.show(event.result.toString());
                Alert.show(addResult);
                backHome();
            }

            private function addUsersFault(event:ResponseEvent):void {
                Alert.show(event.faultString, "Error Executing Call");
            }


            private function backHome():void {
                this.dispatchEvent(new DesgManagementEvent(DesgManagementEvent.DES_HOME));

            } 

    }
}
```

I am able to get the result, but not able to dispatch the event from the custom actionScript class. I googled and got the riposte that you need to add it to display list.

Can anyone figure out where i am going wrong. The method backHome is not being called at all.

Comment: How do you know you are not able to dispatch the event?  Is it a compiler error, listeners not receiving anything, or what?

Comment: the method backHome is not called at all.

Comment: Okay, well is addUsersResult() being called? It's the only place I see  a call to backHome().

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through in the debugger then and seeing why backHome isn't called.  I don't see anything obvious in addUsersResult that would prevent execution from reaching that point.

Comment: How are you checking to see if backHome() is called? Have you tried adding a breakpoint to make sure? Also, what does the DesgManagementEvent class look like?

Comment: That means addUsersResult is not reached.  Use the debugger to step thru the code when addUsersResult is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are expecting to get DesgManagementEvent in the event map and because you don't see it being handled, you believe that bakcHome is not being called.

As you said, events dispatched from an object component that is not in the display list will never reach the event map. You need to pass the dispatcher and use that to dispatch the event. You can pass it in the constructor (first objectBuilder) or as a property (second objectBuilder).

```
<EventHandlers type="{FlexEvent.INITIALIZE}">
  <ObjectBuilder generator="{MyManager}" constructorArguments="{scope.dispatcher}"/>
  <ObjectBuilder generator="{MyManager2}">
    <Properties dispatcher="{scope.dispatcher}"/>
  </ObjectBuilder>
</EventHandlers>
```

If you use the constructor, then it will look something like this:

```
public function MyManager(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher)
{
    this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
}
```

Then you will use your dispatcher property to dispatch the event:

```
dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new DesgManagementEvent(DesgManagementEvent.DES_HOME));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're receiving type String when `addUsersResult()` is called?